# Which is right — "all the three" or "all three" in a situation of specific objects?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, definite-articles, all-the

Let's imagine, I'm speaking about someone's three specific cars, which are over there, there, and there. Now I'm saying that I have installed a new sound system in all of them. Which is right:

> - [...] I have installed a new sound system in all the three cars.
> - [...] I have installed a new sound system in all three cars.

Comment: As it stands, there seems little logical reason to discount either variant, but the 'the' would seldom if ever be used in practice. "I have installed a new sound system in all the three cars that were brought in" doesn't sound unidiomatic, but the 'the' could equally well be omitted in this case.

Comment: @mplungjan ... 'all the cars', 'all of the cars', 'each of the cars', 'each of the three cars' sound more natural than 'all of the 3 cars' (and certainly 'all the three cars').

Comment: there are maybe more cars, but I'm speaking only about three of them (which I have specified before)

Comment: lol, If that's the case, then I'd say, "...in all three of the cars." Incidentally, this might be a question more appropriate for [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: *All three cars* implies that there are *only three* cars. Likewise *all the three cars*, *all of the 3 cars*, etc. all imply there are only 3 cars. If you are trying to refer to 3 cars out of, say, 10 cars, then (1) omit *all*, and (2) say *three of the cars*.

Answer (score 2):

*All three cars* is idiomatic. *All the three cars* is perfectly grammatical: to me it has an implication that you have already somehow designated three particular cars from a larger set. This possibility is not implied by *all three cars* (though it's not excluded by it either).

Answer (score 2):

As TrevorD says, *all three cars* implies that there are only three cars. *Three of the cars* would be the best option if you are referring to three out of several cars. *All the three cars* or *all of the three cars* are both grammatically correct, but sound cumbersome. *All three cars* already implies that you are referring to specific cars; you don't need the article to clarify that these aren't just any cars.

I would say that your best options are *all three cars*, *three of the cars*, or *each of [the] three cars*, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great deal of variation in the number of syllables in quantifier phrases. Quantifiers like *many, few, all, some, each, every, lots,* etc may require an article before the quantifier (*a lot*) or after a preposition (*many men/many of the men*/**many of men*), may require a preposition (**a lot men*) or disallow it (**every of them*), or make it optional.

*All*, in particular, allows an optional *of*, mostly, I suspect, to give a short word with a big meaning a little more bulk with an extra syllable.

So the following noun phrases are **all** grammatical, and equal in meaning, but not equally heavy:

- *All three cars ~ All the three cars ~ All three of the cars ~ All of them: those three cars*

Comment: What I don't get is whether "all the three cars" is equal in meaning to "all three cars".