# all three loop types - no the?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Loops allow stored programs to execute statements repetitively. The MySQL stored
>   program language offers three types of loops:
>
> - Simple loops using the LOOP and END LOOP clauses
> - Loops that continue while a condition is true, using the WHILE and
>     END WHILE clauses
> - Loops that continue until a condition is true, using the REPEAT and
>     UNTIL clauses
>
> With **all three loop types**, you terminate **execution** of the loop with the LEAVE statement.

Is there some kind of explanation as to why we don't need the definite article **the** coming after **all** but before **three loop types**? I think I have encountered this particular grammar structure before but at the time no one seemed to know the answer (but that was on the Yahoo question-answer service).

Yet another thing that bothers me here is why is there no **the** in front of **execution**? Like, **you terminate THE execution of the loop with the LEAVE statement**. Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps a question for English Language Learners http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Related and a possible duplicate: [Which is right — “all the three” or “all three” in a situation of specific objects?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117001/which-is-right-all-the-three-or-all-three-in-a-situation-of-specific-objec). The second question about *execution* has been covered before as well, but it's hard to search for that kind of thing so I don't have a link right now.

Comment: [Quantifiers do not have simple, or even consistent, syntax](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/73985/15299).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With all three loop types, you terminate execution of the loop with the LEAVE statement.

There is nothing wrong with "all three". It's quite correct and is also more commonly used than "all the three". With the second, where you have a noun describing a process as opposed to an object (in this case the execution of a loop), it's quite common to leave out "the". Other examples: "after assembly", "during cooking", "rain stopped play", "the end of term".